# How can I extract the price using importxml from an AngularJS site?

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, regexextract

I need to extract the price from this website using importXML on Google Spreadsheets.

Here is a product
https://en-sa.wadi.com/apple-iphone-6s-16-gb-4g-rose-gold-with-facetime-61616.html

The issue is they are using AngularJS, so the typical method is not working.

This is what I was using earlier, but it's no longer working.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(ImportXML("https://en-sa.wadi.com/sony-xperia-z3-16-gb-4g-lte-black-dual-sim-355.html", "//div[@class='info-module other-sellers']//p"), "{{ctrl.selectedSupplier.suppliers.length-1}}", ""),"[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 4):

When the data you're after is in a script, you can get all script content with xPath `//script`, join the results (so you don't have to rely on the script being 7th or 11th in the source), and parse the results with `regexextract`. The following formula returns 2447 as of now:

```
=regexextract(regexextract(join(" ", IMPORTXML("https://en-sa.wadi.com/apple-iphone-6s-16-gb-4g-rose-gold-with-facetime-61616.html", "//script")), """offerPrice"":\d+"), "\d+")
```

Here, the first regular expression `"""offerPrice"":\d+"` matches `"offerPrice":2447` (the quote character is doubled inside the string). The second `regexextract` keeps only the number 2447.

The above assumes that "offerPrice" is the thing you want. To extract the regular price, use `"""price"":\d+"` instead.

Comment: Worked like a charm..you sir are a genius

Comment: you could also wrap it into one regex and a concatenate function: =regexextract(concatenate(IMPORTXML("https://en-sa.wadi.com/apple-iphone-6s-16-gb-4g-rose-gold-with-facetime-61616.html", "//script")), """offerPrice"":(\d+)")